# Why is jQuery applying effects on different elements at once?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, animation

I have two elements and I want them to fade in, stay  for 3 seconds and then fade out one after another using jQuery, but the effects are applied all at once.

```js
$(() => {
  $("#first").fadeIn(2000).delay(3000).fadeOut(2000);
  $("#second").fadeIn(2000).delay(3000).fadeOut(2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="first" style="display: none;">First<h1>
<h1 id="second" style="display: none;">Second<h1>
```

I tried using `dequeue()` and `stop()` methods, but none of them work. What is causing the problem and is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: The issue is that `.fadeIn()` is *not* an animate effect, so does not go on the animate queue, while `.delay()` delays the animation queue.  Either animate opacity or use the fadeIn callback  `.fadeIn(2000, function() { setTimeout($(this).fadeOut(2000), 3000); })`  (pretty sure there's more than one existing question that explains this in detail)

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you, I will try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling both at the same time, call the second one, after first animation is completed, to achieve this, you can use `.done()`:

```js
$(() => {
  $.when($("#first").fadeIn(2000).delay(3000).fadeOut(2000))
  .done(function(){
  $("#second").fadeIn(2000).delay(3000).fadeOut(2000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="first" style="display: none;">First<h1>
<h1 id="second" style="display: none;">Second<h1>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. If I had more than two elements, do I have to nest all of them like this or is there another way?

Comment: No, then you need to nest in nested (may be a loop): `$.when(    .done(function(){$.when(.done( function(){}))  }));`